# No access plugin was found that supports the account type com.apple.twitter. - STTwitter

Tags: ios, twitter, ios-simulator, sttwitter

I get this error from time to time and I don't understand why.

> No access plugin was found that supports the account type com.apple.twitter.

I have included the Accounts, Twitter & Social frameworks that are required for STTwitter.

For now I can work around the issue by resetting the iOS Simulator, however, I'd like to understand what the underlying problem is.

Comment: STTwitter author here. It's the first time I hear about this issue. Does the problem also arise on the device? Which iOS version? Thank you for the details.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem also and the solution was to remove the twitter app, remove the accounts from the twitter settings, reboot and reinstall everything.

Not sure the reboot was necessary, but better safe than sorry